# CLR Integration to return resultset

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, .net-assembly, clrstoredprocedure

I am integrating CLR with SQL Server 2008, it's successfully configured. but i am calling a webservice inside this SqlProcedure.

Here is the code, i have tried to return xml response.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void SendReceiveAsXML(SqlString request)
{
    SqlPipe sp;
    sp = SqlContext.Pipe;
    MsgWS obj = new MsgWS();
    string s = obj.SendAndReceiveAsXml(request.ToString());

    sp.Send(s);

}
```

There may be a possibility of "maximum length exceeds exception". to prevent this, i need to retrieve the response as reader as well as this is the requirement of end component i am integrating with sql.

[image]

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What line does the exception occur in? Is it in `sp.Send(s);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Pipe.Send(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127319.aspx) is intended for returning messages back to the client. For such a large piece of text, you should probably create an [`SqlDataRecord`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqldatarecord.aspx), to return this to the client as a result set - where you can effectively return it as a `varchar(max)` column.

---

So, you'd edit the end of your method to this:

```
string s = obj.SendAndReceiveAsXml(request.ToString());

var md = new SqlMetaData("ColumnA", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1);
var row = new SqlDataRecord(md);
row.SetString(0, s);

sp.Send(row);
```

Comment: do SqlDataRecord support multiple record set? because if i convert the response to dataset, it returns me multiple recordset. any suggestion.

Comment: @asdasd - Why are you converting it to a dataset? If you already have it as a `string`, you can store that as a single column in a single row, provided the column is `varchar(max)`.

Comment: actually, this is the requirement for other application to accept the output as datatable from sql.

Comment: `Pipe.Send(SqlDataRecord)` sends a single row result set - the consuming code will see it as a data table.